# frequency of a particular element of a sequence in its subsequences

Tags: permutations, combinations

How to find the **frequency** of a **particular element** of a sequence( with distinct elements) of **e** elements in its all subsequences  **of a particular length**  say **l**.

*I tried to proceed using permutation and combination , but it is giving wrong answer.*

Any better method to solve this?

Comment: I don't understand. If the elements are all distinct, what's the point of considering the frequency? I guess I'm missing something ...

Comment: I am saying to count the frequency not in sequence itself but in all its possible subsequence of length L.

Comment: This is too vague. Show us your work where you "tried to proceed using permutation and combination" and got the wrong answer, and maybe we can point out where you made your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A= Total number of subsequence of length **l** =  $ e C l $

B= Total number of subsequence of length **l** without particular element = $(e-1) C l$

So required result is  A - B = $ (e-1)C(l-1) $